# Dict type is not hashable in case of Json, tried sets as well

Tags: python, json

I am doing a project for my school. I am trying to convert a dict to json, so i can post it as a json request.

Here's the sample dict which i am trying to get as json.

```
dict = {
        {'subject': 'testing123',
         'start': {
             'dateTime': "2020-06-13T21:30:02.096Z",
             "timezone": "UTC"},
         'end': {
             'dateTime': "2020-06-20T21:30:02.096Z",
             'timezone': 'UTC'}
         }
    }
```

I tried first normally by loading it in json but failed by error 'timezone': 'UTC' is not serilizable.

so i checked on google and then i tried to dump it in json and load it in up in json as variable. i.e

```
dict_json = json.dumps(dict)
dict_json = json.loads(dict)
print(dict_json)
```

but again got the hashing error.

then i tried to search on google again and found out i have to convert them to tuple if i have multiple dictionaries not sure on this one though if this is a right finding.

```
dict = {
        tuple({'subject': 'testing123',
         'start': tuple({
             'dateTime': "2020-06-13T21:30:02.096Z",
             "timezone": "UTC"}),
         'end': tuple({
             'dateTime': "2020-06-20T21:30:02.096Z",
             'timezone': 'UTC'})
         })
    }
```

then it became a set and set is also not Json serializable now, ran out of options. Need suggestion on this problem to convert this dict into a valid json format.

Comment: Your issue that dictionary keys must be hashable, and you have a dictionary key that is another dictionary (and hence not hashable)

Comment: That was never a dict in the first place. Also, `tuple{` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I tried it also with a list and then tried using function .toJson but that also ` dict_json = dict.toJson()
    print(type(dict_json))` but it also gave an error unhashable 'dict'

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sorry Sir, that was a typo fixed the dict, when i try to use it as json it throws an exception not serializable.

Comment: @Chris_Rands any way sir, which you can suggest to hash nested dictionaries into a json ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word tuple and the parentheses that go with it. Next every entry in the dict must have a `key` and a `value`. The first level of your dict does not have a pair like that. Here is what I believe to be your intended object:

```
dict = {
           'subject': 'testing123',
           'start': {
               'dateTime': "2020-06-13T21:30:02.096Z",
               'timezone': 'UTC'},
           'end': {
               'dateTime': "2020-06-20T21:30:02.096Z",
               'timezone': 'UTC'}
        }
```

here is the result of performing your test case on this object:

```
>>> dict = {
...            'subject': 'testing123',
...            'start': {
...                'dateTime': "2020-06-13T21:30:02.096Z",
...                'timezone': 'UTC'},
...            'end': {
...                'dateTime': "2020-06-20T21:30:02.096Z",
...                'timezone': 'UTC'}
...         }
>>> json_dict = json.dumps(dict)
>>> dict_from_json = json.loads(json_dict)
>>> dict_from_json
{'subject': 'testing123', 'start': {'dateTime': '2020-06-13T21:30:02.096Z', 'timezone': 'UTC'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2020-06-20T21:30:02.096Z', 'timezone': 'UTC'}}
>>> dict_from_json['subject']
'testing123'
```

Comment: sorry sir, it's the original dict tuple was a typo my bad, when you will try to parse this dict as json it fails. It's not serializable.

Comment: I updated the answer to show the serialized result from my console @SidKaushik. In shorter terms, you had an extra set of braces.

Comment: got it thanks thanks a lot. silly mistake i thought that's how we are supposed to create nested dicts.